# Winamp - Remove "L" Keyboard Command

Tags: winamp

I posted this previously and I didn't get any answer, so I thought it was worth re-sharing to make sure it didn't get missed:

Short and sweet: I have Resource Hacker downloaded, and I've deleted every reference I can find to the "L" key, but...when the main window is selected, even though it doesn't appear in any of the menus, pressing the "L" key still causes the "Open File" dialog to pop up. The objective is to remove that behavior, but I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm missing.

The reason I'm trying to get rid of this piece is that the playlist I have has grown to epic proportions, and sometimes when I want to jump to a file, Winamp hangs, and for reasons I can't explain, it jumps to the main window, and sometimes what I'm trying to type into the search box gets read by the main window as a keyboard command instead. (So if the track name has an "S", Shuffle gets turned off, if there's an "L", it opens the dialog box, and so on.) The issue being, opening the Open File dialog box causes it to hang even longer.

Can anyone that knows the Winamp executable better than I do help me on this one? Or is there a better tool to try than Resource Hakcer?

Comment: Autohotkey and remap that key combo when the WinAmp main window is in focus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WinAmp: Delete keyboard command "L"](https://superuser.com/questions/1770864/winamp-delete-keyboard-command-l)

Comment: ...no because that question doesn't actually have an answer.